# Struggling to de-couple my Database logic from my Account session logic

Tags: php

I have new `Account.php` class that I am attmepting to use for all account-related functions on my website. This class file takes a database connection as it's constructor:

```
private $db;

public function __construct(
    Database $db
) {
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

One of these Account class functions is a simple `start_session` function like so:

```
//Start User Session
public function start_session()
{
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

On the top of all my website files, I have an include file called `session_check.php` which was basically starting a session and checking if a REMEMBER_ME cookie was enabled to keep the user logged in.

I've refactored and trimmed the code down like so:

```
//Include autoload.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'credentials.php';

//Use Account+Database class
use MyApp\Account\Account;
use MyApp\Database\Database;

//Create a Database instance with appropriate parameters
$database = new Database($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

//Pass the Database instance to the Account constructor
$account = new Account($database);
$account->start_session();
//Also check if user is remembered
$account->authenticate_rememberme_user();
```

However, now I fear this may not be an optimial approach. When I call `new Database()` I am opening a database connection. So now, for every page that needs to start a session using `start_session()`, a database connection is also opened. This is starting to feel like a poor implementation.

I'm thinking of changing the `Account.php` class to not accept the connection as part of it's constructor and to simply pass a database connection to the necessary Account class functions where needed. But I am also unsure if this is an optimal approach.

Any insight would be welcome.

My Database class is opening a connection like so:

```
public function __construct(
    private string $host,
    private string $username,
    private string $password,
    private string $database
) {
    $this->connect(); //This opens the connection
}
```